# override image in listview, display using picasso

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso

i am new in android.i display images in list view using Picasso library but the problem is that when i scroll down images are override and scroll up images override.please help me out.

I think what happened when i login 1st time at that time looks perfect list view,but once i logout and immediately login(without close application)then i see images are override.

so please give me solution

Homepage.java

```
superDistributorlist = new listview_data[]
                        {
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.adduser, register),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.topuptransfer, topup),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.memberdebit, mdebit),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.voucher, voucher),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.complaint, complaint),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.complaintstatus, complaint_status),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.changesmspin, smspin),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.changepwd, changepwd),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.mobilenochange, change_mobileno),
                                new listview_data(R.drawable.table2, reports)
                        };
                adapter = new ListviewAdapter(HomePage.this, R.layout.listview_item_row, superDistributorlist);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view; // get the parent layout view
                        TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle); // get the child text view
                        final String item = tv.getText().toString();
                        Intent i;

                        if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_Registration))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, Registration.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_topup))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, TopupTransfer.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_changesmspin))) {
                            Log.d("Item2 ", "" + item);
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ChangeSmspin.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_changepwd))) {
                            Log.d("Item3 ", "" + item);
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ChangePwd.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_complaint))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ComplaintRegister.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_reports))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ReportList.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_complaint_status))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ComplaintStatus.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_mdebit))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, memberdebit.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else if (item.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.changemobileno))) {
                            i = new Intent(HomePage.this, ChangeMobNo.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }

                    }

                });
            }
```

ListviewAdaper.java

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listview_data> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    listview_data data[] = null;
    ImageLoader imgloader;
    String url;

    public ListviewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, listview_data[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        imgloader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        listHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new listHolder();
            listHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (listHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        listview_data list = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(list.title);
        //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(list.icon);
        Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(listHolder.imgIcon);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(list.icon)
                .resize(48,48)
                .error(R.drawable.imagenotavailable)
                .into(holder.imgIcon);
        return row;
    }

    static class listHolder
    {
        static ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit() // will explain later
            .into((ImageView) convertView);
```

And with holder pattern,

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(history.icon).into(holder.imageIcon)
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change
listHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

TO

holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

Comment: i do that but not get output properly

Comment: Can you please post the code from where you set the adapter @Varshil shah